# Since when is Python None equal to None?

Tags: python, equality, nonetype

I always thought that Python nulls are not equal, as is common in many other languages and based on simple logic (if the value is unknown, how can it be equal to another unknown?).

However, recently I tried it, and discovered that:

```
Python 3.10.2
>>> None == None
True
```

Has it always been this way? If not, which version changed it?

Comment: I'm not confusing it with `NaN`, @Barmar, the question is about `None` not `NaN`. I was actually thinking of things like SQL `NULL`.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that the official documentation continues to refer to `None` as ["the Null object"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-null-object).

Comment: SQL NULL is like NaN. Python None is not.

Comment: Evidently it is, based on the answer to me question which is effectively asking *whether* the Python None is like SQL NULL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None has always been equal to itself in python. "None == None" has always evaluated as true.

As seen from this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html

> Since None is a singleton, testing for object identity (using == in C) is sufficient.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but do you have a link to where this is defined in the language spec?

Comment: Surely unless otherwise documented, you'd expect all values to be equal to themselves.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html check "The None Object"

Comment: @CalebCarson: That doesn't actually say anything about how None behaves in a Python == comparison. It makes a brief reference to the entirely different *C* == operator, but it doesn't say anything about Python ==.

Comment: @user2357112, sure, you _could_ have explicitly documented contrary behavior in Python without it being contrary to the C API docs, but in absence of that explicit documentation (as [exists for NaN](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nan) f/e), the default behavior for a singleton is very relevant.

Comment: @kindall That's why I'm asking for the documentation 

Comment: @user2357112 It says right there that "testing for object identity is sufficient".

Comment: Because None is a singleton (only accessed from one point in memory) it can only ever be a single value, therefore == to itself will always result in True. Hope that clarifies things @user2357112

Comment: Every object [compares equal to itself](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) unless otherwise defined and documented; `None` is not so otherwise documented, and `type(None).__eq__` is not defined and is inherited from `object`.

Comment: @CalebCarson: You can have singletons that don't compare equal to themselves. Singleton-ness isn't special here. The default `==` behavior for singletons is the default behavior for objects in general, and can be overridden just like it can for any object.

Comment: @Dommondke: In context, that's saying that you don't need a type check to check whether a value is None the way you would to check if a value was an int or something like that, because there's only one instance of None's type, so an identity comparison against None suffices as a type check. It doesn't actually say anything about how Python `==` comparisons behave with None.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit statement that `None == None` is true, but as far back as Python 1.5.2, there are two statements that imply this.

First, in a [discussion of the equality operator](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ref/comparisons.html):

> Comparison of objects of the same type depends on the type:
>
> - Numbers are compared arithmetically.
> - Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents (the result of the built-in function `ord()`) of their
>   characters.
> - Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of corresponding items.
> - Mappings (dictionaries) are compared through lexicographic comparison of their sorted (key, value) lists.<sup>[5.2](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ref/comparisons.html#foot3253)</sup>
> - **Most other types compare unequal unless they are the same object**; the choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger
>   than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one
>   execution of a program.

*Every* use of `None`, though, [refers to the same object](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/lib/typesother.html#SECTION004177000000000000000)

> #### 2.1.7.7 The Null Object
>
> This object is returned by functions that don't explicitly return a
> value. It supports no special operations. **There is exactly one null
> object, named `None` (a built-in name).**
>
> It is written as `None`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, this has to do with how None == None is evaluated by the __eq__.

None is a singleton object, which means that there is only one instance of it in memory at any given time. When you assign a variable to None, you are simply creating a reference to this single instance of None.

So, your example is like saying "does *None* point to the same object in memory as *None*?". The answer is yes, therefore __eq__ is fulfilled (True).

[This link will explain equality in great depth if you want to read up on it.](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-hashing-and-equality-in-python-with-hash-and-eq-12f6da79e8ad)

Comment: `None == None` could theoretically still be defined (and implemented) as `False` even if `None` is the same object in memory as `None`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 are you proposing to implement equality checking in a manner different to stdlib implementation? In that case I agree, but I don't think that would be within the scope of this question. Python has always avoided ambiguity and the evaluation of None == None (or None is None) would, and should, always return True.

Comment: `float.__eq__` looks around nervously.

Comment: @chepner Yeah...well...can't satisfy them all I suppose haha. I feel bad saying there are necessary exceptions we need to account for but that is unfortunately the case here. I do think understanding the issue with float representation in binary to be one of those though, sooner or later everyone stumbles on this issue in their own work I would think.

Comment: `float` (or more specifically, IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic) had more practical concerns than mathematical purity :)